# Simulator don't appearing in the list of available devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am need test project on older device iPhone 7 and 6 but I can't add simulator for running. I am open list of iOS Simulator press "Add Additional Simulator..." and I am selected device which I am want, but how Run this device if I am show this simulator after closing window.[List of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiqHl.jpg)

Comment: you can check - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGOviWHPNjQ

Comment: I know this video, but it can't help me, it's very stupid question, I am feel shame)))), but I don't know why I can't start my app on older devises like < iphone8, In the past I am don't have this problem but when xcode is updated to new version I am obtain surpsire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem just fixed after one week without my manipulation, xcode updated and problem disappear.